# How to power Nodemcu using 12 volt AC to DC adapter?

Tags: nodemcu

I am trying to make a small project using Nodemcu. My project is WiFi controlled LED, 2 LED's will blink at the same time. I have successfully uploaded the code and it works fine using USB connection. But I want to power the Nodemcu using 12 volts 1.5 amps AC to DC adapter. I have checked it in web search but I have not found an understanding circuit. please help me out guys.

Answer (score 1):

You connect the + side of the adapter to VIN pin and the - side to GND.

You have to check the maximum voltage when using the VIN pin. Probably it means you 'waste' some power (but it's from a wall wart, so it should be ok). See the remark of Flyingfenix below for heating consequences.

See this link: [Power Related ESP-12E Development Board Pins](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/), fragment 'Using a Wall Wart':

[image]

Examples: [Wall-Mount-AC-Adapters](https://nl.mouser.com/Power/Power-Supplies/Plug-In-AC-Adapters/Wall-Mount-AC-Adapters/_/N-brwlv?P=1yxt7f5)

The current (1.5A) should be more than enough; the adapter's current should be higher than what is needed by the NodeMCU + circuit. So this is ok.

Comment: Thankyou Michel Keijzers. I will go ahead and try the connection today. cheers..!!

Comment: Please note that the regulator used (AMS1117 3.3V or equivalent) is a linear regulator, meaning that it "wastes" everything above 3.3V as heat. Using a 12V or above supply and loading the module's outputs/using wifi means it will run _very hot_ - possibly even damaging it. Use, if possible, a 5V wall wart - temperatures will be much lower.

Comment: @Flyingfenix Thanks for the remark, I put a forward in my answer to your comment.

Comment: NodeMCU is not an Arduino and I've seen [stories](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=515532.0) about them burning up when supplied with voltage too high.

Comment: @S.Imp Thanks for that remark, I removed the +20V as I cannot find it (anymore).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers your answer is pretty helpful. You might offer a link to [3.3V wall warts](https://www.mouser.com/Power/Power-Supplies/Plug-In-AC-Adapters/Wall-Mount-AC-Adapters/_/N-brwlv?P=1yxt7f5) or to one of the voltage regulators mentioned [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199863/how-to-step-12v-to-5v-and-3-3v)

Comment: You could just use a buck converter or linear regulator outside the NodeMCU, and power it with 5V, it will save your NodeMCU's tiny SMD components, If you look on the underside of most of these boards, the given maximum is 10V and recommended 5V